# Was the tariff that Alexander Hamilton wanted to create (in his Financial Plan) ever put into action by Hamilton?

Tags: united-states, economy

Hamilton's Financial plan had 3 parts:

1. The U.S. government would pay all debts
2. The U.S. government would create a national bank
3. The U.S. government would impose a high tax on imported goods (tariff)

I know that the tariff was originally declined by the government, but was it ever put into action? Did Hamilton convince the government to accept the tariff, or did someone else convince the government? If so, when was it put into action (the year is fine)?

Comment: "Hamilton recommended that a tariff be levied on foreign imports to protect domestic industries and discourage imports, as well as raise government revenue. This was the only major Hamilton proposal to be rejected by Congress. In 1791, however, Hamilton was able to convince Congress to pass an excise tax on whiskey." [HistoryCentral](https://www.historycentral.com/NN/economic/Hamiltontorescue.html)

Comment: "[The Tariff Act of 1789](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tariff_of_1789) was the first major piece of legislation passed in the United States after the ratification of the United States Constitution ..." In what way did that not qualify? (FWIW, I think I can see the answer to that question by reading through Mark's link, but said answer should be edited into the question).